# Iphone user input structure

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to iPhone development and I am looking at exactly what is shown in the picture to allow users to write input.
But I cannot find what exactly is it! Are those some special kind of UITextFields? Are they a special kind of UITableView? What is it?

[image: What I am looking for]

Answer (score 3):

This is a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell's that contain UITextFields. You can easily do this by loading your UITableViewCell from custom XIB files, in which you've dropped UITextFields. As far as the "hints" you see in each field, that's the "Placeholder" property of UITextField.

Answer (score 1):

Those are grouped tableviews with custom table cells that contain textfields and single line etched separators. Make sure to set the style to "grouped"

Answer (score 0):

The above basically consist of UItableviewCell with a Uitextfield within it.

If you are on ios5 (which i assume you will be), you can add UItableviewcontroller from you Interface Builder and from there, taking the advice to set the style of the table to "grouped".

you should have the similar outlook of the above for the background.

In here, if you select a cell you should have the option to set a few different style to your uitableview cell.

If none of the default styles works for you, just select custom and add your own uitextfield or uibutton.

Note: There's a bit of difference between prototype cell.